# Random quote page reload javascript

Tags: javascript, html, random, message

I am attempting to have the page reload with a different message in each part. I thought I had it perfectly but cannot figure out why it isn't showing exactly.

here is the code

Html

```
<div id="words"></div>
```

And here is the Javascript

```
var words = new Array();
words[0] = " loves you";
words[1] = "Would you like  to tuck you in?";
words[2] = " is here for you";
words[3] = "Did you know that  can be in 2 places at once?";
var random = Math.ceil (Math.random()*words.length) - 1;
$('words').set('html', words[random]);
```

Comment: You haven't included jQuery, at a guess. Or whichever library you were intending to use, that uses `$` as an alias. And, if you *are* using jQuery, you should be using `$('#words')`; but I haven't come across the `set()` method before, is that a plug-in?

Comment: I wasn't consciously using a plug-in. I thought the $ sign was normally used for jquery as well. I tried to add a few cdn's but it still didn't help at all. I retrieved the code from another suggestion on how to do so online

Answer (score 0):

The section with "$" is using JQuery. It's possible that you have not included the JQuery library and it therefore does not understand the $ operator

Try putting this in the header of the page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still is not working